# Trouble with matchmaking in iOS with gamekit and game centre

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, gamekit, game-center

At the moment I'm trying to add online multiplayer to my iOS game (that uses UIKit) using gameKit/GameCenter for matchmaking. I'm trying to present game center's matchmaker interface but with varied success. I have two view controllers (with respective .xib files), `mainMenuViewController` and `onlineViewController`, along with a file called `GCHelper.h`.

In `CGHelper` I have this:

```
- (void)findMatchWithMinPlayers:(int)minPlayers
                     maxPlayers:(int)maxPlayers 
                 viewController:(UIViewController *)viewController             
                       delegate:(id<GCHelperDelegate>)theDelegate 
{
    if (!gameCenterAvailable) return;   

    self.presentingViewController = viewController;
    delegate = theDelegate;               
    [presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init]; 
    request.minPlayers = minPlayers;     
    request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;

    GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];    
    mmvc.matchmakerDelegate = self;

    [presentingViewController presentModalViewController:mmvc animated:YES];
}
```

I use this function in my views to show the matchmaking interface. At first I tried it in `mainMenuViewController`, which is my first view controller using this:

```
[[GCHelper sharedInstance] findMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:2 viewController:self delegate:self];
```

And that worked fine but that's not where I wanted to do it, so I tried the exact same thing from `onlineViewController` and nothing happens, no error, just the blank view of `onlineViewController.view` stares back at me. I'm fairly new at this so I'm wondering if it's down to how I'm dealing with the views, here's the code I use to switch from the `mainMenu` to the other view:

```
-(IBAction)showOnlineView 
{
    OnlineViewController *onlineViewController = [[OnlineViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OnlineViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIView *currentView = self.view;
    UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];
    [currentView removeFromSuperview];
    [theWindow addSubview:onlineViewController.view];
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, I'm not sure how I should deal with going back to the main menu if the user presses cancel (although that may become self evident once I've got this working, I just thought I'd mention it in case this lack of knowledge on my part makes it obvious I'm going about the whole thing incorrectly).

Comment: Hi, I am on the same boat... do you find an answer for this? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment and I'm probably too late for this but I never did; I don't suppose you did?